# Undefined PHP output from ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, tcpdf

I'm looking to create a PDF file through ajax via TCPDF. Everything works perfectly, PDF is saved in the server I pass the URL to my HTML

```
$responseArray = array('id' => 'Success', 'message1' => 'Hello', 'message2' => '/pdfgen/genpdf/'.$filetitle.'.pdf');
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);             echo $encoded;
```

Then I get redirect. The problem is although my browser console tab shows what PHP has sent which is

> {"id":"Success","message1":"Hello","message2":"/pdfgen/genpdf/1703419677.pdf"}

back on the HTML file I can't assign the URL to a variable.

## it just prints undefined.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "path to php",
    data: ({mob: mob}),
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var id = data.id;   
    var message1 = data.message1;
    var message2 = data.message2;
});
```

Comment: You get back value as data and you try to assign as response.id. change response with data : var id = data.id

Comment: You must set header like this: header('Content-Type: application/json');
and the JS file has wrong, you must use data.id not response.id

Comment: your callback has the parameter `data` but you are trying to use `response`??

Comment: @Sfili_81 It was all response but I changed to data in trial error process. I unified it now and still the same issue.

Comment: @RaminRezazadeh I tried to set the header but then I ran into another issue which says you can't send header again because TCPDF through static file send headers

Comment: @RamRaider I tried with both data and response all field unified. still faced the same issue not defined.

Comment: This error is shown when you want to download the pdf file, but I don't see a download file in your response. please check in your codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'path to php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {mob: mob},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response); 
    }
});
```

Comment: For who get the same problem. please explain how this answer resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

just replace data with response

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url    : "path to php",
        data: ({mob: mob}),
        dataType: 'json',
        })
.done(function(response) {
        console.log(data);
        var id = response.id;   
        var message1 = response.message1;
        var message2 = response.message2;
        alert(message2 );
        });
```

Comment: Please format your answer with appropriate tag. And give some explanation how your answer can help please

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code `response.id`, `response.message1` and `response.message2` with
 `data.id, data.message1 and data.message2`. SInce you have used `data` in your success function

Answer (score 0):

Hope help:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "path to php",
    data: ({mob: mob}),
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function(response) { <-- edit
    console.log(response); <-- edit
    var id = response.id;   
    var message1 = response.message1;
    var message2 = response.message2;
    alert(message2);
});
```